# How to setup a DataContract to match the complex XML input in WCF 4.0 REST Service

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a XML structure like this:

```xml
<Message>
    <Messagehead>
        <OSType>Android</OSType>
        <RouteDest>SiteServerName</RouteDest>
        <ActionType>Enroll</ActionType>
    </Messagehead>
    <MessageBody>
        <Raw>
            <![CDATA[OrienginalMessageContent]]>
        </Raw>
    </MessageBody>
</Message>
```

and I want upload this XML to WCF 4.0 my rest service:

```
public string Enroll(Message instance)
{
    // TODO: Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection
    return "success";
}
```

the `Message` is a `DataContract` type, I setup it like below:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Message
{

    [DataMember]
    public MessageHead MessageHead { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public MessageBody MessageBody { get; set; }


}

public class MessageHead
{
    public OSType OSType { get; set; }

    public string RouteDest { get; set; }

    public Action Action { get; set; }
}

public class MessageBody
{

    public string RawRequestContent { get; set; }
}
```

but when I get the `Message` instance from the server side, all the property is `null`, except the `OSType`, can anybody tell me why? How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Whatc out: `Message` is a pre-defined type in the WCF runtime - maybe you should call your class something else - something a bit more meaningful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides being a really bad name for a class (since it's already used in the WCF runtime), your `Message` class also has some flaws:

```
<Message>
    <Messagehead>
       ....
    </Messagehead>
```

Your `<Messagehead>` has a lower-case `h` in the middle - yet your class defines it to be upper case:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public MessageHead MessageHead { get; set; }
```

This will **not work** - case is important and relevant in a WCF message! If your XML has a lower-case `h`, so must your `DataContract` class!

Your XML also requires a `<Raw>` tag inside your `<MessageBody>`

```
<MessageBody>
   <Raw>
        <![CDATA[OriginalMessageContent]]>
   </Raw>
</MessageBody>
```

yet your data contract doesn't respect that:

```
public class MessageBody
{
    public string RawRequestContent { get; set; }
}
```

Again - those don't line up! Names are important - and they **must match** between your XML representation of the message, and the C# class representing that message.....